# How to upgrade from Qt4 to Qt5 with Anaconda

Tags: python, qt

I need to update from Qt4 to Qt5 to use Spyder. I have done `conda update qt` but I have remained on version 4.8.7.

I am already on PyQt5 (5.9.2), which may be relevant.

Comment: Qt4 with Qt5 can coexist together, so the idea of upgrade does not exist, remove Qt4 and install Qt5.

Comment: @eyllanesc as simple as `conda uninstall qt` then `conda install qt`?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/qt